# Crashlytics doesn't report the crash

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I used Crashlytics, But It doesn't report the crash.

Analytics And Cloud messaging are ok, just Crashlytic doesn't work.

I added this to my Manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
```

But the issue persists.

Debug Mode Log:

> 09-05 09:15:50.876 11583 11583 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,**"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false**},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"5f4cde52d6a994c993000030","bundle_id":"com.aradteam.rbela"},"expires_at":1599303988714}

Gradle Project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
       // google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aradteam.rbela"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 4
        versionName "3.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:round-corner-progress-bar:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    //retrofit
    def retrofit2_version = '2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit2_version"

    //rxjava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0"

    //room
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    def archLifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"

    //navigation
    def nav_version = '2.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    //exoPlayer
    def exo_version = "2.11.7"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exo_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exo_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exo_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:$exo_version"

    def lottieVersion = '3.4.1'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    //glide
    def glide_version = '4.11.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    // WorkManager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"


    //FireBase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'

}
```

Comment: follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: you are using old version of Google Crashlytics. Go to through the new and updated library

Comment: I did but it doesn't work @chandmohd

Comment: I used the last version on google's doc 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android
@Vikas

Comment: i also faced some problem about 3-4 days ago do these simple steps
1. Test Your app in different device
2. Change app environment Debug to Live

Comment: Have you been able to get past the onboarding screen in Crashlytics (the one that asks you to build, run, and hit a test crash)?

Comment: @Ali Any luck with this yet?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Vikas Testing app on different device helped me, thanks for leaving this comment!